# Access embedded resources in a .NET program by ID using Windows API functions

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi, interop, winforms-interop

I have added an .ICO icon image to a .NET WinForms program using the Resources page in the projects options. Is it possible to access this resource using Windows API functions like [LoadImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea), ideally by specifying a resource ID (in native code done using the MAKEINTRESOURCE macro if the icon is referenced in the .RC resource file)? Or is it necessary to load the icon resource using .NET framework methods and to afterwards provide the icon handle to the API function?

Comment: Open the executable with a rc editor, if resources are visible, then the answer is yes.

Comment: You can load the Assembly (`Assembly.LoadFile()`), then use the `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` method to extract any the `.resource` parts and use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()` to save it (disc or MemoryStream). Finally, use the [ResourceReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcereader) class to extract any of the resources contained in any of the `.resource` parts that the loaded Assembly contains. No API required.

Comment: Well, if the above fits the requirements but you think you need an example, let me know.

Comment: @Jimi: Thanks for pointing this out, but I am using a Windows API function and P/Invoke; so this is a definite requirement.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for pointing this out, but a resource editor does not show the added icon resource in the EXE.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to PInvoke these resources? Using the .Net features, you can achieve the same result and keep your application portable.

Comment: @Jimi: My main aim was to clarify whether it is possible at all to directly access the resources embedded in the .NET executable via Windows API calls. If not, I can use .NET ways to for example load an icon and pass the handle to the Win32 function, but I wanted to clarify the issue first.

Comment: If you want to extract a .Net Assembly's default Icon, you could call `FindResource(Ex)`, `LoadResource`. If you want to get the internal embedded resources, use the .Net native methods. Those methods kown what they're looking for. If you could describe what is this all about, you'ld receive better support.

Comment: Okay, so, like, I know the answer to this and I've written an extensive library.  This comes with a very large BUT... BUT, I wrote it in VB.NET in a very unorthodox manner. I also wrote a swiss army knife replacement for IntPtr in VB .NET with a backend written in pure CIL.  

However, I know exactly how to do it p/Invoke, so if you want, just let me know, I'll walk you through it.

Comment: Better yet, if you want the projects, I can link you to those.  If it's for a Windows native platform, the libraries can be accessed across languages.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is my Github repository](https://github.com/ironywrit/nmdt) with my latest iteration of my Windows Desktop toolkit, named DataTools.

It is written in VB.NET but at its core there is some pure CIL coding so it's very fast.

The library can be included in either VB or C# projects for use in the Windows Desktop environment.

It includes MemPtr, which is a drop-in replacement for IntPtr.

Since you are very interested in grabbing resources from EXE files, look at the DTInterop project, specifically DataTools.Interop.Desktop.Resources.

I spent a great many years on this entire project.  It's clean, it holds together well, and the VB is easily translatable to C#; that the interop methodology is still the same.

I did a lot of homework and listened to a lot of ancient Windows gurus, along the way, most of whom have their home in the straight-C language Win32 API of legend and old.

My code is heavily commented and documented, so you shouldn't have any problem figuring out which way is up.